# positive even number code help in java (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",)

Tags: java

below is my java code

```
package javaApp;

public class EvenSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int even[] = new int[num];
        int sum = 0,j = 0;
        String evennums = "";
        for(j=0; j<=num; j++) {
            if(num%2==0) {
                even[j]=num;
                sum=sum+num;
                args[j]= Integer.toString(num);
            } 
            evennums=String.join(",", args);
          } 

        System.out.println(evennums);
        System.out.println(sum);
    } 
}
```

with the above code, I want to achieve java application to generate comma-separated positive even numbers and also calculate their sum.

Comment: please describe your expectation and your goal. what's the problem with this code?

Comment: what are the args that you passed while running the app?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian I am usning online editor 
https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/ to test the code

Answer (score 1):

By utilizing the `java8` `Arrays.setAll` and `Arrays.stream` methods we can replace the `for-loop`.

```
package javaApp;

import java.util.*;

public class EvenSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input the amount of even numbers: ");
        int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        int evens[] = new int[n];
        Arrays.setAll(evens, i -> i * 2);
        int sum = Arrays.stream(evens).sum();
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens));
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could write this with a single `for-loop`statement:

```
package javaApp;

import java.util.*;

public class EvenSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input the amount of even numbers: ");
        int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        int evens[] = new int[n];
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            evens[i] = 2 * i;
            sum += 2 * i;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens));
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Output (with an input of 6):

```
Input the amount of even numbers: 6
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
30
```